# Excel VBA Add Worksheet: "That command cannot be used on multiple selections"

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Excel 2010:

For the record, this code has been working for months. The last two weeks, however, it has stopped working with the error described in the title. I have made no changes to the code in that time, which leads me to believe it is the environment that has changed.

```
Sub TableofContents(CurrMonth, CurrYear, Z, Region, RegionName)
    Sheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "1. Table of Contents"  '<---- BREAKS HERE
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With Columns("A:A")
        .ColumnWidth = 6
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 48
    Columns("C:E").ColumnWidth = 11
    With Range("A3:E3")
        .MergeCells = True
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = "Table of Contents"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    With Range("A5:B25")
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 11
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    Range("B:B").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Select Case Region
      [Lots of boring code filling in the TOC]
    End Select
End Sub
```

The line at which it breaks is the second line, the line trying to add a sheet at the beginning of the workbook. For the record, on ALL tabs, the only cell selected is cell A1, and no sheets are grouped together (the title bar of Excel says nothing about groupings). I have tested for Hidden sheets and VeryHidden sheets and none are present.

On a MAYBE related note, another part of the code inserts a sheet in another part of the workbook and IT is putting it in the wrong place (I tell it before Sheet 4, it is putting it before Sheet 3). Again, I checked for Hidden and VeryHidden sheets and found none.

I am beginning to think one of those last Excel updates broke the code. Last time it disabled ActiveX controls I had written and I had to change everything into forms, which was annoying. I am unsure how to work around this error.

Comment: I have also tested editing the line and removing all code down to Sheets.Add and it still refuses to add a new sheet.

Attempting to add new sheets manually causes the same error in the workbook. It is a freshly generated workbook, so it isn't some historical error.

Comment: Under the Review tab could you check to ensure there is no protection on the workbook structure?  That's one thing that may throw an error (not sure if it would be this error though)

Comment: We never want to hear this. But at some point we need to look at the possibility that there could be some corruption in the workbook. Try creating a brand new workbook and putting your code and copy the required sheets into the new workbook. See if it still gives an error.

Comment: @Soulfire  There is no protection on the workbook at all.

@ MatthewD Each of these workbooks is created from a new workbook each time the macros are run. In this particular instance, the files were created from blank workbooks about 3 minutes before the error occured.

Comment: Just for arguments sake, would you mind trying `thisworkbook.Sheets.Add
` in the immediate window on a newly created file?

Comment: I was able to duplicate this problem following [these steps](https://scottlyerly.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/excel-geeking-that-command-cannot-be-used-on-multiple-selections-error-on-a-single-cell/): 1) `Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden` 2) `Sheet1.Activate` 3) `ThisWorkbook.Save` 4) `ThisWorkbook.Close`. The next time you open the file, Sheet1 will be visible. When you try to insert a new sheet you get the error. I fixed it by hiding Sheet1

Comment: @Ralph I tried that and that worked fine.   ---- I have a theory. I only tested it once before I had to move to other projects but the workbook which has this error has several pivot tables. I disabled saving caches with the file, saved the file, closed the file, reopened the file, and was able to THEN insert a sheet. This leads me to believe the problem is actually pivot cache related, despite what the error message says, but I have only one test to base this upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Pivot Caches elsewhere in the workbook. Somehow they had become corrupted (despite being less than 10 minutes old) and they were preventing any new tabs from being added to the workbook.

So, I wrote a subroutine that 'wipes' all the pivot caches in the workbook by setting to false the SaveData variable, then saving the file. Elsewhere in the code it closes and reloads the file, which then runs the second part of this subroutine to switch the settings from False back to True (which usually requires a refresh first) and then re-saves.

```
Sub RebuildAllPivotCaches(Switch)
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    If Switch = "TurnOff" Then
        For Temp = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            On Error GoTo SkipTemp
            If Worksheets(Temp).Visible = True Then Worksheets(Temp).Activate
            For Each PivTable In Worksheets(Temp).PivotTables
                PivTable.RefreshTable
                If ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivTable.Name).SaveData = True Then ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivTable.Name).SaveData = False
            Next PivTable
SkipTemp:
        Next Temp
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Else
        For Temp = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            On Error GoTo SkipTemp2
            If Worksheets(Temp).Visible = True Then Worksheets(Temp).Activate
            For Each PivTable In Worksheets(Temp).PivotTables
                PivTable.RefreshTable
                If ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivTable.Name).SaveData = False Then ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivTable.Name).SaveData = True
            Next PivTable
SkipTemp2:
        Next Temp
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```